# Building Erlang OTP R15B from source in cygwin using jdk javac & jar, cygwin make, install, gcc and ld

Tags: erlang, makefile, cygwin, ld

Does anyone know how to get Erlang built in cygwin?

I downloaded the Erlang OTP R15B source in my cygwin installation.
Gunzipped and untarred the source.
Then I did a `./configure --prefix=/usr` and then `make install`

Screenshot of all my steps below.

```
# wget the Erlang source (for UNIX systems)
wget "http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B.tar.gz" -O "$HOME/erlang/otp_src_R15B.tar.gz"

# tar -zxvf the tarball
tar -zxvf "$HOME/erlang/otp_src_R15B.tar.gz"

# Go to the location of the code
pushd "$HOME/erlang/otp_src_R15B"

# Create perl5 symlink for perl
ln -s /usr/bin/perl.exe perl5.exe

# Configure the build
./configure --prefix=/usr
    ...
    *********************************************************************
    **********************  APPLICATIONS INFORMATION  *******************
    *********************************************************************

    wx             : wxWidgets not found, wx will NOT be usable

    *********************************************************************
    *********************************************************************
    **********************  DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION  ******************
    *********************************************************************

    documentation  :
                     fop is missing.
                     Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.

    *********************************************************************
```

I was able to get past the javac paths problem by using the following script in `/usr/bin/javac.exe`

```
$ cat /usr/bin/javac.exe
#!/bin/bash
#
# A wrapper for calling javac from Cygwin.
# Tries to convert any arguments that are Unix-style paths into
# Windows-style paths.  This includes any arguments to classpath or
# sourcepath or any arguments that begin with / .
#

ME="`basename $0`"
JAVAC_EXEC="$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac"
ARGS=""

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
   arg="$1"
   shift
   case "$arg" in
      -cp | -classpath)
         arg="$arg' '`cygpath -p -w "$1"`"
         shift
         ;;
      -sourcepath)
         arg="$arg' '`cygpath -p -w "$1"`"
         shift
         ;;
      /*)
         arg="`cygpath -p -w "$arg"`"
         ;;
   esac
   ARGS="$ARGS '$arg'"
done

eval "set -- $ARGS"
#echo "$JAVAC_EXEC" "$@"
exec "$JAVAC_EXEC" "$@"
```

Also added `/usr/bin/jar.exe` as follows:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/jar.exe
#!/bin/bash
#
# A wrapper for calling javac from Cygwin.
# Tries to convert any arguments that are Unix-style paths into
# Windows-style paths.  This includes any arguments to classpath or
# sourcepath or any arguments that begin with / .
#

ME="`basename $0`"
JAR_EXEC="$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar"
ARGS=""

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
   arg="$1"
   shift
   case "$arg" in
      -cp | -classpath)
         arg="$arg' '`cygpath -p -w "$1"`"
         shift
         ;;
      -sourcepath)
         arg="$arg' '`cygpath -p -w "$1"`"
         shift
         ;;
      /*)
         arg="`cygpath -p -w "$arg"`"
         ;;
   esac
   ARGS="$ARGS '$arg'"
done

eval "set -- $ARGS"
#echo "$JAR_EXEC" "$@"
exec "$JAR_EXEC" "$@"
```

Also, modified `otp.mk` file setting CLASSPATH to expected windows paths as follows:

```
Line
172     .java.class:
173         CLASSPATH=`cygpath -wp $(CLASSPATH)` $(JAVA) $(JAVA_OPTIONS) $<
174     
175     
176     $(JAVA_DEST_ROOT)$(JAVA_CLASS_SUBDIR)%.class: %.java
177         CLASSPATH=`cygpath -wp $(CLASSPATH)` $(JAVA) $(JAVA_OPTIONS) -d $(JAVA_DEST_ROOT) $<
```

I was finally ready to do the installation

```
# Make 
make install

...
make[6]: Entering directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src'
ld -shared -o ../priv/lib/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.so ../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o -lc -lutil -ldl -lm
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `my_alloc_binary':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:606: undefined reference to `driver_alloc_binary'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:608: undefined reference to `__getreent'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `write_until_done':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:632: undefined reference to `__getreent'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `my_alloc':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:591: undefined reference to `driver_alloc'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:593: undefined reference to `__getreent'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `my_driver_select':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:916: undefined reference to `driver_select'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `clean_que':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:736: undefined reference to `driver_free'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:744: undefined reference to `driver_free'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `close_unlink_port':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:820: undefined reference to `driver_free'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:820: undefined reference to `driver_free'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `trace_ip_ready_output':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:523: undefined reference to `driver_free'
../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o: In function `trace_ip_start':
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src/trace_ip_drv.c:371: undefined reference to `set_port_control_flags'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000779.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__close'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000994.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__fprintf'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000913.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__exit'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001041.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__fwrite'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001602.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__send'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000032.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp____errno'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000934.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp___fcntl64'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001300.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__memcpy'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000669.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__accept'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001513.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__read'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001304.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__memset'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001706.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__sscanf'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001690.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__socket'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001636.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__setsockopt'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d000723.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__bind'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001119.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__getsockname'
/usr/lib/libc.a(t-d001239.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__listen'
i686-pc-cygwin/Makefile:100: recipe for target `../priv/lib/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.so' failed
make[6]: *** [../priv/lib/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.so] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/make/run_make.mk:38: recipe for target `release_spec' failed
make[5]: *** [release_spec] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/make/otp_release_targets.mk:119: recipe for target `release' failed
make[4]: *** [release] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/make/run_make.mk:38: recipe for target `release' failed
make[3]: *** [release] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools/c_src'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/make/otp_subdir.mk:28: recipe for target `release' failed
make[2]: *** [release] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/runtime_tools'
/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/make/otp_subdir.mk:28: recipe for target `release' failed
make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib'
Makefile:899: recipe for target `install.libs' failed
make: *** [install.libs] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to get past this step?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wrong. If you read better you should see this line:
`javac: directory not found: /home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/jinterface/priv/`

From what I can understand, the following error messages are simply there 'cause is the unwinding of the compilation stack.

Does the directory really exists or not?
Give more information, please!

Comment: You're right. I should have looked at the end of the error messages. The `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/jinterface/priv/` directory exists. I'm going to try to run the javac command manually to see if there's something to be changed. There could be any number of issues relating to the JDK settings as it is outside of cygwin. It is in my Windows PATH (as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin) and my cygwin PATH (as /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin) More to follow.

Comment: javac can't process cygwin paths (i.e. `/home/Dragos/erlang/otp_src_R15B/lib/jinterface/priv/`). Is there a way to get javac for cygwin?

Comment: I think you just have to adjust env variables: http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#execute

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo, I used the `javac.exe` and `jar.exe` bash scripts above to handle cygwin to Windows path conversions. Now, I've got a new problem with the `ld` loader and some undefined function references in `C` source files.

Comment: Has the make step finished? I'm quite confused about you issuing a make install and ld kicking in!! If make step finished, you should find bin and libs...

Comment: No, make did not finish, make kicked out the stack at `ld -shared -o ../priv/lib/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.so ../priv/obj/i686-pc-cygwin/trace_ip_drv.o -lc -lutil -ldl -lm` I'll try to compile with in cygwin using VS command line tools per instructions at [http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/couchdb/trunk/INSTALL.Windows](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/couchdb/trunk/INSTALL.Windows) The cygwin gcc compiler and tools just seem to give me error after error. It would be nice though to get erlang built in cygwin the same way it gets built in Linux with the gcc tools.

Comment: unfortunately unix-line doesn't mean full compatibility. By the way your error seems related to ld not finding a needed library: do you have any insight on this? Maybe it's just a path problem!

Comment: I believe the lib is erl_driver.h I will add that to the path and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: You can also check this for more insight: http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL-WIN32.html . It seems that you're are right about the VS tools...